# Unicode name regex

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, character-properties

I found many links about this, but none of them did not work me. I used `\p{Letter}`, it allowed space and digits.

I want Unicode Regular Expression for person name. Only letters like English, Latin, Russian, Chine and other Europe countries etc. languages, which does not allow digits, space and specally symbols. Can anybody help me? I will use that in jquery validation engine and in c# code.

Comment: Some people's names have punctuation in them. I am sure they will hate you for this.

Comment: I did not know that..So, I need regex which not allow space, digits at least.

Comment: Names can also contain numbers, but I guess you can require them to use roman numerals then, which I think is the norm anyway with Latin names at least... :) No idea about other cultures and names there.

Comment: OMG. can names contain numbers?  So, I come to a conclusion that, should I remove validation?

Comment: Why do you want to validate a name

Comment: Do you look it up in a Grand Name Database too

Comment: I try users to enter their REAL name. not any digits, space, symbols. In future I will need their real name and surnames. It is not 100%, but to use validation will help me about 20% that, users will enter theirs real name forced.

Comment: There is no way to get their real names ("Hey look, another NotJohn McFakeName!") unless they *want* to give them. If you truly need their real names (do you really?), making them aware of that need is the best you can do. If someone tries to input their real name and your "validation" refuses it, well, you won't get their real name.

Comment: Okay, I think that, validation should be for only length. thanks for all

Comment: If by length validation you mean "> 0", then yeah. "O" is a valid surname, and there has been people named "X".

Comment: yeah? I had meant length > 2... So, I will use only "required"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the W3C recommendations for dealing with personal names: http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names

I don't think you'll find regular expressions very useful for this. You would have to allow pretty much everything, except maybe strings that don't contain any letters at all.